# Permission error when trying to deploy to Google Cloud Run

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I'm getting a permission error when trying to deploy an image to cloud run:

```
gcloud beta run deploy endpoints_proxy \
    --image="gcr.io/endpoints-release/endpoints-runtime-serverless:1.30.0" \
    --allow-unauthenticated
```

This is the error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.run.deploy) User [email-goes-here] does not have permission to access namespace [project-id-goes-here] (or it may not exist): Cloud Run does not have permission to get access tokens for the default compute service account, 1088973916567-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com. Please give Google Cloud Run Service Agent the permission iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken on the default compute service account.
```

My account has owner and editor permissions, I even tried attaching the Cloud Run Service Agent role.

I also tried adding these roles to the "default compute service account" listed in the error, didn't work.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The error message is very misleading, the error occurs because the **Cloud Run Service Agent** was missing.

After creating the following service account:

```
Name: service-<account-id>@serverless-robot-prod.iam.gserviceaccount.com
Role: Google Cloud Run Service Agent
```

The problem got solved. Looks like Cloud Run needs this service account to work, so don't ever delete it :)

Comment: Right, cloud run needs this account to pull image from your project

Comment: Can you expand this answer? How did you create the service account and what roles/permissions were applied? How did the service account get deleted?

Comment: I think you need the setup the service account robot when you try to deploy container images from other GCP projects
https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/deploying#other-projects

Comment: The service account got deleted manually and it was a mistake. To recreate it I just used the same email prefix as other service account agents with the @serverless-robot domain. The only role attached was the Google Cloud Run Service Agent.

Comment: I just posted this answer hoping it might help someone in the future as I was stuck for hours, if you have some better explanation on why this service account is needed it'll be great to have, as the documentation in Google Cloud Run was really not useful

Comment: Generally when you enable some service (such as Cloud Run) in cloud console it starts to set up everything needed for that to work. One of this things is to create default compute service accounts.

 It's needed because Cloud Run needs `iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken` permission, which can be related for example to the role `roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator`, and that role must be assigned to the service account

Comment: I have that service account and this role attached to it. For me the error still occurs. When I've tried to find the role in https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/roles it didn't show up. Does this role exist for you guys?

Comment: How are you able to create a google-managed service account? It doesn't let me create service accounts with a custom domain `@serverless-robot domain.`

Comment: Carrots, you don't need to create a new service account. The service account described already exists and is managed by GCP. Instead, go to the IAM page of the Cloud Console (https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam) and click "Add" at the top of the window to add the service account and role.

Comment: I totally forgot about this. That helped so much @CarlosMartinez, thank you! For others, as Christopher said may, depending on your setup, need to be applied like this: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/deploying

Comment: This is not a good practice: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-agents . Service Agent Roles should not be bonded to others principals.

Answer (score 13):

You should **enable** permissions to the Cloud Build service account.
It won't work unless you do so.

Google Cloud Console > Cloud Build > Cloud Build Settings > enable access to the GCP services that you are using.
(see the images attached)

[Cloud Build Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NL2xu.png)

[Cloud Build Panel - enable services that you want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ta08q.png)

Comment: this worked but makes not sense, If I'm using a credentials file with cloud run admin permisions, I wouldn't need to still give direct access on cloud build itself.
But thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the `service-<project-id>@serverless-robot-prod.iam.gserviceaccount.com` is not present in GCP console, just run this command:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding --member=serviceAccount:service-<project-id>@serverless-robot-prod.iam.gserviceaccount.com --role=roles/run.serviceAgent <project-id>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, just make sure billing hasn't expired. When mine did, I got these opaque errors (such as this one) that didn't reference to billing in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Search for service accounts in the console. select the default compute service account. Then click "Permissions". Then click "Grant Access". Add the service account email address (of the account you made) to the principals. Assign the "Service Account Admin" role.

Answer (score -1):

*Cloud Run Service Agent* is a service agent role: you should not bind Service Agent Roles to principals that are not service agents.

The answer above by @carlos-martinez is not a Google good practice: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-agents

Comment: Hey there, I'd gladly accept your response if you could provide an alternative solution. I haven't been using GCP for a few years.

Comment: @CarlosMartinez's answer is specifically talking about a Google created _service agent_ that runs Cloud Run actions. When Google first created that account, `Cloud Run Service Agent` is the role that it receives, so when rebuilding it (if accidentally deleted), adding the role `Cloud Run Service Agent` is the desired outcome since we are trying to replace the accidentally deleted agent. Also, this doesn't seem to be an answer to the original question about invalid permissions, so in general, just leave it to your comment above!